# Mapping UML Class Diagram in Eclipse (modelling tools) to actual Classes

Tags: eclipse, uml, reverse-engineering

I'm looking at a "reverse-engineerable" modelling system for students in Eclipse.

Currently, I'm looking at the Eclipse modelling tools in the Ganymede release (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-modeling-tools-includes-incubating-components/ganymedesr2)

I'm happy with the UML modelling design surfaces in Eclipse for building UML models.

But, does anyone know how to map these to code and back and forth?

I'm a little spoiled, because I do this all the time in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Eclipse ships reverse engineering by default, but I'm sure vendors like Omondo may have (even free) plugins for that.

But I saw forward- and reverse-engineering (also for sequence diagrams!) in [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) (also free). It looked quite usable.